# Error using joystick_remapper

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to use the joystick_remapper, and I'm getting the following error every time I run the code:

```
[ERROR] [1349147615.365296561]: Client [/joystick2] wants topic /logitech to have datatype/md5sum [joy/Joy/e3ef016fcdf22397038b36036c66f7c8], but our version has [sensor_msgs/Joy/5a9ea5f83505693b71e785041e67a8bb]. Dropping connection.
```

My launch file looks like this:

```
<launch>

<node pkg="joy" type="joy_node" name="joystick1" >
  <remap from="joy" to="logitech" />
</node>

<node pkg="joystick_remapper" type="joystick_remapper.py" name="joystick2" >
  <remap from="joy_source" to="logitech" />
  <remap from="joy_des" to="joy" />
  <param name="button_mapping" type="str" value="=" />
  <param name="axis_mapping" type="str" value="=" />
</node>

</launch>
```

Can someone tell me how to make this work? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44913/error-using-joystick_remapper/) by [sgwhack](https://answers.ros.org/users/2844/sgwhack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-10-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-01**:
Why is the node name in the error message `joystick2`? That name doesn't appear in the launch file.

**Comment by [sgwhack](https://answers.ros.org/users/2844/sgwhack/) on 2012-10-02**:
I just named it...What should it be? I've tried other stuff, it doesn't seem to matter...unless its something specific that im missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a previous thread:
http://answers.ros.org/question/11417/datatypemd5sum-error-with-p2os_teleop/

---

Originally posted by [sgwhack](https://answers.ros.org/users/2844/sgwhack/) with karma: 73 on 2012-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0